# Flaky S4 method dispatch

Tags: r, methods

I was testing to see if I could support models fitted using the **cplm** package in **emmeans**, and I ran across some very odd behavior for the `terms` method. Here is an example:

```
library(emmeans)
library(cplm)

data(mtcars)

m <- cpglm(mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp, data = mtcars)
```

The function `emmeans:::recover_data.lm` seemed to have some promise of working correctly. It just calls the `terms` method on the object and passes it on to other functions. However, it doesn't work:

```
> emmeans:::recover_data.lm(m)
 Error in slot(x, name) : 
  no slot of name "terms" for this object of class "cpglm"
```

Digging further, I verify that `terms()` does work in the global environment:

```
> terms(m)
mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp
... (remaining lines excluded) ...
```

However, it does not work in `recover_data.lm`:

```
> debug(emmeans:::recover_data.lm)
> emmeans:::recover_data.lm(m)
    ...

Browse[2]> terms(object)
Error in slot(x, name) : 
  no slot of name "terms" for this object of class "cpglm"

Browse[2]> getMethod("terms", "cpglm")
Error in getMethod("terms", "cpglm") : 
  no method found for function 'terms' and signature cpglm
```

However...

```
Browse[2]> getMethod("terms", "cplm")  ## cpglm inherits from cplm
Method Definition:

function (x, ...) 
attr(x@model.frame, "terms")
    ... etc. ...

Browse[2]> methods("terms")
[1] terms,ANY-method  terms,cplm-method terms.default*    terms.formula*    terms.gls*       
[6] terms.merMod*     terms.terms*     
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code

Browse[2]> selectMethod("terms", "cpglm")
Method Definition:

function (x, ...) 
attr(x@model.frame, "terms")
    ... etc. ...
```

So, in the namespace for **emmeans**, I can verify that we "know" that there is a `terms` method for `cpglm` objects, and we can find it via `selectMethod()` but not via `getMethod()` or by just calling `terms()`. This is very odd, especially since the documentation for `selectMethod` seems to promise it should work:

> The function `selectMethod()` returns the method that would be selected
>   for a call to function `f` if the arguments had classes as specified by
>   `signature`.

Finally, I am able to verify that this seems to have something to do with a conflict in dispatching S3 methods:

```
> stats::terms(m)
Error in slot(x, name) : 
  no slot of name "terms" for this object of class "cpglm"
```

Is there a way to get my package **emmeans** to work correctly when there is a mix of S3 and S4 methods; in particular, to look for S4 methods before S3 methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation entry in `Methods_for_S3`:

> The reasons for defining both S3 and S4 methods are as follows:
>
> 1. An S4 method alone will not be seen if the S3 generic function is called directly. This will be the case, for example, if some function calls unique() from a package that does not make that function an S4 generic.

The `cplm` package exported an S4 method for `terms`,
but not one for S3,
which you can see [here](https://github.com/actuaryzhang/cplm/blob/46416b40b3ebe29c0c7cc41b6dd84baec0531fbf/NAMESPACE).
This automatically makes `terms` an S4 generic when you attach `cplm`.
However, `emmeans` calls the S3 generic from `stats`,
and that's what causes the problem.

You can work around it by defining an S3 generic in the global environment that dispatches to the S4 generic:

```
terms.cpglm <- function(x, ...) {
    cplm::terms(x, ...)
}
```

but you should let the `cplm` maintainer know that he should define S3 and S4 methods if he's transforming an S3 generic into an S4 one.

Comment: Thanks. And the reason for not just using S3 methods exclusively is ... ?  Only reason I can think of is those very rare, complicated cases where you need a signature involving classes of more than one argument.

Comment: @rvl Well, if every package using an S3 generic sticks to S3, then there's no problem, that's why it ends up being the responsibility of the package who changes to S4.

Comment: So, inasmuch as a main goal is always to produce reliable code, wouldn’t it be recommended practice, when an S3 generic exists, to produce only S3 methods and not S4 ones? It seems to me that having two object dispatch systems operating in parallel increases errors (as I’ve illustrated) and reduces performance.